# Explicit isomorphism $H_n(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have read that one can explicitly show that $H_n(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ by proving that $$\mathbb{Z} \to H_n(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n) \qquad , \qquad n \to [n \cdot \textrm{Id}_{\Delta^n}] $$ is an isomorphism, $n >1$. How should I proceed to show this?

Comment: Proceed by induction.

Comment: I would also like to see a from scratch proof of this, without using the long exact sequence of a pair method. 

I would start like this: Following Rotman, with $Z_n(\Delta^{n},\partial \Delta^{n})=\left \{ \gamma\in S_n(\Delta^n):\partial \gamma\in  S_{n-1}(\partial \Delta ^n) \right \}$ and  $B_n(\Delta^{n},\partial \Delta^{n})=B_n(\Delta^{n})+S_n(\partial \Delta^{n}),$

Comment: then it's not hard to show that $H_n(\Delta^n,\partial \Delta^{n})\cong Z_n(\Delta^n,\partial \Delta^n)/B_n(\Delta^{n},\partial \Delta^{n}).$

This means that an arbitrary element of a coset of $H_n(\Delta^n,\partial \Delta^{n})$ has the form $a +b+c$ where $\partial a=0;\ b=\partial d\  \text{for some}\  d\in S_{n+1}(\Delta^n)$ and $c\in S_n(\Delta^n).$

Define $\Phi:\mathbb Z\to H_n(\Delta^n,\partial \Delta^{n})$ by $\Phi(j)=[j\cdot 1_{\Delta^{n}}].$ Clearly $\partial 1_{\Delta^{n}}=0$ so $\Phi$ is well-defined.

Comment: Suppose $[j\cdot 1_{\Delta^{n}}]=[k\cdot 1_{\Delta^{n}}].$ Then, $(j-k)\cdot 1_{\Delta^{n}}=b+c=\partial d+c$, were $b,\ c$ and $d$ are as above. Now then 

$\partial ((j-k)\cdot 1_{\Delta^{n}})=\partial (\partial d+c)\Rightarrow (j-k)\partial 1_{\Delta^{n}}=\partial c\Rightarrow \partial c=0, $ so $c$ is a cycle and so $(j-k) 1_{\Delta^{n}}-(a+c)$ is both a cycle and a boundary. Not sure how to continue...

Comment: What do you mean by "explicitly"? It seems that you directly consider  the singular chain complex. Which results can be used? $H_n(\partial \Delta^n)$ being generated by the sum of all faces of $\Delta^n$?